# Как установить mod_wsgi на Windows Server

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

Команда

```
pip install mod_wsgi
```

выдает следующую ошибку:

```
 'missing Apache httpd server packages.' % APXS)
        RuntimeError: The 'apxs' command appears not to be installed or is not executable. Please check the list of prerequisites in the documentation for this package and install any missing Apache httpd server packages.
```

Как установить apxs?  И что делать дальше?

Answer (score 1):

Никак нельзя - modwsgi не собирается под Windows. Можно пробовать извращаться с Cygwin, но тогда туда еще нужно и Apache, и Python установить.

А apxs - это бинарник для сборщика модулей Apache. В Ubuntu, к примеру, его можно достать установив apache2-dev.

Есть запасной выход - скачать уже скомпилированный модуль. Отсюда, например - https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst Необходимо скачать модуль, который в точности совпадает с версией Apache и Python. Я бы в этом случае начал с самого-самого начала - скачивания только той версии апача, для которой есть компилированный модуль. Из-за того, что версии должны совпадать установить скомпилированный модуль тот еще головняк, причем Apache в случае неудачи не сыплет ошибками типа "не ту версию скачал" - ошибки будут совсем не связаны с истинной причиной.